# NFS Server in Java

Tags: java, filesystems

I search an implementation of a network (or distributed) file system like NFS in Java. The goal is to extend it and do some research stuff with it. On the web I found some implementation e.g. [DJ NFS](http://users.csc.calpoly.edu/~jbergami/projects/djnfs/), but the open question is how mature and fast they are.

Can anyone purpose a good starting point, has anyone experience with such things?

P.S. I know Hadoop DFS and I used it for some projects, but Hadoop is not a good fit for the things I want to do here.

--EDIT--
Hadoop is really focused on highly scalable, high throughput computing without the possibilities to overwrite parts of a file and so an. The goal is you could use the filesystem e.g. for user home directories.

--EDIT--
More Details: The idea is to modify such a implementation so that the files are not stored directly on a local filesystem, but to apply data de-duplication.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at [dcache.org](http://www.dcache.org).
They implement a NFSv4.1 server in Java.

- [whitepaper](https://www.dcache.org/manuals/dcache-whitepaper-light.pdf)
- [github](https://github.com/dCache/nfs4j)
- [manual](https://www.dcache.org/manuals/book.shtml)

Answer (score 3):

You may want to take a look at [Alfresco JLAN](http://www.alfresco.com/products/aifs/):

> Alfresco JLAN uses a virtual file system interface that allows you to plug in your own file system implementation with the core server handling all of the network protocol exchange between the client and server. JLAN is also the only Java implementation of Window’s CIFS (Common Internet File System), in addition to supporting NFS and FTP.

Answer (score 1):

I can't say I've actually played with anything other than HDFS, but here are some links that might help you.

- http://www.hirednetwork.com/?p=61
- http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/freeabs_all.jsp?arnumber=1266109
- http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchDistributedFileSystem

Answer (score 1):

Checkout [YANFS](http://blogs.oracle.com/shepler/entry/yanfs_is_the_new_webnfs)
I haven't used it, but it might be worth looking at. The project page is  [here](https://yanfs.dev.java.net/) over on java.net and you have to get at the source with  [CVS](https://yanfs.dev.java.net/source/browse/yanfs/)